# Making UIContainerView as wide as device screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

I can't seem to correctly reason about this problem so I was hoping someone could give me some tips to guide me along.

So I have 4 UIContainerView's WITHIN a UIScrollView. 
As the User swipes, the Containers display 4 individual UIViewControllers.

What I want is, through autolayout, to specify that each UIContainerView must take up the device screen's width. So as a user scrolls, one UIViewController is shown at a time on the entire screen

The problems I am running into: 
1. Can't make a IBOutlet from UIContainerView .. not sure why
2. No way in autolayout to specify "device screen width" within a UIScrollView

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking here. There's no `UIContainerView` class, although a view can be used as containers for the content view of another view controller. You can use auto layout constraints to make a view as wide as its superview, but there's no way to use the screen itself (nor should you do that, considering the recently announced multitasking). Please clarify your question. A picture might help.

Comment: Try to check this code: https://github.com/kitasuke/PageMenu
or 
https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController

they also store views in a queue and make them reusable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UIScrollView must be contained inside a UIViewController nib. Make constraints from your container view for equal widths to your view controller's view in Interface builder, and then place all container views next to each other using AL.